# iOS 7 CAEmitterLayer spawning particles inappropriately

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation, ios7, caemitterlayer

Strange issue I can't seem to resolve where on `iOS 7` only, `CAEmitterLayer` will spawn particles on the screen incorrectly when birth rate is initially set to a nonzero value. It's as if it calculates the state the layer would be in the future.

```
// Create black image particle
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
CGContextFillRect(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), rect);
UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

// Create cell
CAEmitterCell *cell = [CAEmitterCell emitterCell];
cell.contents = (__bridge id)img.CGImage;
cell.birthRate = 100.0;
cell.lifetime = 10.0;
cell.velocity = 100.0;

// Create emitter with particles emitting from a line on the
// bottom of the screen
CAEmitterLayer *emitter = [CAEmitterLayer layer];
emitter.emitterShape = kCAEmitterLayerLine;
emitter.emitterSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.size.width,0);
emitter.emitterPosition = CGPointMake(self.view.bounds.size.width/2,
                                      self.view.bounds.size.height);
emitter.emitterCells = @[cell];

[self.view.layer addSublayer:emitter];
```

I saw on the DevForums one post where a few people mentioned they had similar problems with `iOS 7` and `CAEmitterLayer`, but no one had any ideas how to fix it. Now that `iOS 7` is no longer beta, I figured I should ask here and see if anyone can crack it. I really hope this isn't just a bug that we have to wait for `7.0.1` or `7.1` to get fixed. Any ideas would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

YES!

I spent hours on this problem myself.

To get the same kind of animation of the `birthRate` we had before we use a couple of strategies.

Firstly, if you want the layer to look like it begins emitting when added to the view you need to remember that `CAEmitterLayer` is a subclass of `CALayer` which conforms to the `CAMediaTiming` protocol. We have to set the whole emitter layer to begin at the current moment:

```
emitter.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime();
[self.view.layer addSublayer:emitter];
```

> It's as if it calculates the state the layer would be in the future.

You were eerily close, but actually its that the emitter was beginning in the past.

Secondly, to animate between a birthrate of 0 and n, with the effect that we had before we can manipulate the lifetime property instead:

```
if (shouldBeEmitting){
    emitter.lifetime = 1.0;
}
else{
    emitter.lifetime = 0;
}
```

Note that i set the `lifetime` on the emitter layer itself. This is because when emitting the emitter cell's version of this property gets multiplied by the value in the emitter layer. Setting the `lifetime` of the emitter layer sets a multiple of the `lifetime`s of all your emitter cells, allowing you to turn them all on and off with ease.

Comment: Oh wow, thank you so much! I had just given up and written my own particle generator which doesn't perform quite as well. Setting the beginTime was all I needed to do because I'm not animating the birthrate. The app I'm working on is being submitting in less than two days, so you saved the day! Thanks!

Comment: This solution fixes the big mess but still it doesn't become 100% identical to the old behavior. I get less particles emitted, and there are some other weird side effects.

Comment: Thank you so much! This has been bugging me for months.

Comment: I spent so much time trying to only change the `birthRate`. The idea with the `lifetime` is extremely good! The behavior with `beginTime` is still really weird to me, but it fixed all my issues. Pretty happy to have found a great 10-year-old solution to my 2023 struggles.

Answer (score 2):

For me, the issue with my CAEmitterLayer, when moving to iOS7 was the following:

In iOS7 setting the CAEmitterLayerCell's duration resulted in the particle not showing at all!

The only thing I had to change was remove the cell.duration = XXX and then my particles began showing up again.  I am going to eat an Apple over this unexpected, unexplained hassle.

Comment: Bingo!  Thank you!  Because of your answer I commented out just the [_CAEmitterCell setDuration:2.0]; line in my code, reran under the iOS 7 simulator, and it works!