# CAEmitter smooth start of animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, caemitterlayer, caemittercell

I am trying to have a CAEmitterLayer make a kind of lightsaber animation. I want a beam of light to appear from a point and stop. My problem is that I cannot get the beginning of the animation to happen smoothly. As soon as I run the code it just appears as if a couple of seconds have already passed without any animation.

I stripped down the code as much as possible to see if I could find the source of the problem, but even at its simplest it still happens. Here is a sample of the code I have right now which still has the problem:

```
CAEmitterLayer *emitterLayer = [CAEmitterLayer layer];
emitterLayer.emitterPosition = CGPointMake(10, 10);

CAEmitterCell *emitterCell = [CAEmitterCell emitterCell];
emitterCell.contents = (id)[[UIImage imageNamed:@"LightParticle"] CGImage];

emitterCell.birthRate = 100;
emitterCell.lifetime = 10;
emitterCell.velocity = 10;

emitterLayer.emitterCells = @[emitterCell];
[self.view.layer addSublayer:emitterLayer];
```

I'm guessing that I must have missed something obvious but I haven't been able to fix this for days.

Setting the birthRate to 0 will cause the beam to disappear smoothly, but setting it back to any number will cause it to appear with no animation again.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Finally found the answer to this here:
[iOS 7 CAEmitterLayer spawning particles inappropriately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18913484/ios-7-caemitterlayer-spawning-particles-inappropriately?rq=1)

This is what I was missing:

```
emitter.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
emitterCell.birthRate = 0.1;
emitterCell.lifetime = 10;
emitterCell.velocity = 10;
```

birthRate could be very small but not 0.

Then change the scale speed

emitterCell.scale=0.01;
 emitterCell.scaleSpeed=0.1;

hope this can give you some ideas.

Comment: I tried it, this makes it so that instead of multiple light particles there is only one, not even close to a beam. It still does not start from where it should, starts about 1 or 2 seconds later in the animation.

Comment: It should give you a beam.

Comment: birthRate = 0.1 would make it so that only one particle is created every 10 seconds. The particle is a ball of light, therefore all that is happening is that a single ball is moving to the right and then reappearing at the beginning after 10 seconds. Adding the scale speed just makes it grow slowly until the end.

Comment: you may add more emitter cells to treat the ball as a emitter      ……………………...emitterCell.contents = (id)[[UIImage imageNamed:@"LightParticle.png"] CGImage];
  
    emitterCell.lifetime=10.0;
  emitterCell.velocity=10;
    emitterCell.birthRate=0.1;
    CAEmitterCell *emitterCells = [CAEmitterCell emitterCell];
    emitterCells.contents = (id)[[UIImage imageNamed:@"LightParticle.png"] CGImage];

    emitterCells.lifetime=10.0;
    emitterCells.velocity=0;
    emitterCells.birthRate=10;
    
    emitterCell.emitterCells=@[emitterCells];
    emitterLayer.emitterCells = @[emitterCell];

Comment: that still does nothing to make it look like a light saber