# CAEmitterLayer not timing correctly with CACurrentMediaTime() and sometimes not showing at all

Tags: ios, swift, caemitterlayer, caemittercell

I am currently making a particle emitter using CAEmitterLayer and ran into the issue of the layer preloading the animation when I start it and hence the particles all over the place when I show it.

Many answers have said the culprit is CAEmitterLayer being preloaded and we simply have to set its beginTime to CACurrentMediaTime() on the emitter.

See:

[CAEmitterLayer emits random unwanted particles on touch events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11440982/caemitterlayer-emits-random-unwanted-particles-on-touch-events)

[Initial particles from CAEmitterLayer don't start at emitterPosition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29994236/initial-particles-from-caemitterlayer-dont-start-at-emitterposition)

[iOS 7 CAEmitterLayer spawning particles inappropriately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18913484/ios-7-caemitterlayer-spawning-particles-inappropriately?noredirect=1&lq=1)

For me this solution has not worked, when running it on device, iPad Air running iOS 12.1, the emitter often does not show and sometimes it is showed with a great delay.

To illustrate this issue I made a project on github: 
https://github.com/roodoodey/CAEmitterLayer/tree/master/CAEmitterLayerApp

Here is the main code, I have 7 different images for particles chosen at random and a button to show the emitter when pressed.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var particleImages = [UIImage]()
    var emitter: CAEmitterLayer?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black

        // Populate the random images array for the particles
        for index in 1..<8 {
            if let image = UIImage(named: "StarParticle00\(index)") {
                particleImages.append(image)
            }

        }

        // Button pressed to make the emitter emit the particles
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: view.frame.width * 0.5 - 60, y: view.frame.height * 0.5 - 40, width: 120, height: 80))
        button.setTitle("Emit!", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(changeButton(sender:)), for: .touchDown)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addEmitter(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(button)

    }

    @objc func changeButton(sender: UIButton) {
        sender.alpha = 0.5
    }

    @objc func addEmitter(sender: UIButton) {

        sender.alpha = 1.0

        // IF an emitter already exists remove it.
        if emitter?.superlayer != nil {
            emitter?.removeFromSuperlayer()
        }

        emitter = CAEmitterLayer()
        emitter?.emitterShape = CAEmitterLayerEmitterShape.point
        emitter?.position = CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.width * 0.5, y: self.view.frame.height * 0.5)
        // So that the emitter starts now, and is not preloaded. 
        emitter?.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime()

        var cells = [CAEmitterCell]()
        for _ in 0..<40 {
            let cell = CAEmitterCell()
            cell.birthRate = 1
            cell.lifetime = 3
            cell.lifetimeRange = 0.5
            cell.velocity = 500
            cell.velocityRange = 100
            cell.emissionRange = 2 * CGFloat(Double.pi)
            cell.contents = getRandomImage().cgImage
            cell.scale = 1
            cell.scaleRange = 0.5
            cells.append(cell)
        }

        emitter?.emitterCells = cells

        view.layer.addSublayer( emitter! )

    }

    func getRandomImage() -> UIImage {

        let upperBound = UInt32(particleImages.count)
        let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform( upperBound ))

        return particleImages[randomIndex]
    }


}
```

Here is a short 20 second video of the app running on device, iPad Air running iOS 12.1, not run through xcode. https://www.dropbox.com/s/f9uol3yot67drm8/ScreenRecording_11-25-2018%2013-19-29.MP4?dl=0

If somebody could see if they can reproduce this issue or shed some light on this strange behavior it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have a ton of experience with Core Animation although I have to admit not a lot with CAEmitterLayer.  Everything looks right and for a person that knows CALayer pretty well, setting the beginTime with CACurrentMediaTime() makes sense.  However, I ran your project and saw it was not working. For me setting the beginTime on the cell had the effect I would expect.
**Meaning**

```
//delay for 5.0 seconds
cell.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + 5.0
cell.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() //immediate
cell.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() - 5.0 //5 seconds ago
```

Entire File

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var particleImages = [UIImage]()
    var emitter: CAEmitterLayer?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black

        // Populate the random images array for the particles
        for index in 1..<8 {
            if let image = UIImage(named: "StarParticle00\(index)") {
                particleImages.append(image)
            }

        }

        // Button pressed to make the emitter emit the particles
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: view.frame.width * 0.5 - 60, y: view.frame.height * 0.5 - 40, width: 120, height: 80))
        button.setTitle("Emit!", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(changeButton(sender:)), for: .touchDown)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addEmitter(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(button)

    }

    @objc func changeButton(sender: UIButton) {
        sender.alpha = 0.5
    }

    @objc func addEmitter(sender: UIButton) {

        sender.alpha = 1.0

        // IF an emitter already exists remove it.
        if emitter?.superlayer != nil {
            emitter?.removeFromSuperlayer()
        }

        emitter = CAEmitterLayer()
        emitter?.emitterShape = CAEmitterLayerEmitterShape.point
        emitter?.position = CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.width * 0.5, y: self.view.frame.height * 0.5)
        // So that the emitter starts now, and is not preloaded.
        var cells = [CAEmitterCell]()
        for _ in 0..<40 {
            let cell = CAEmitterCell()
            cell.birthRate = 1
            cell.lifetime = 3
            cell.lifetimeRange = 0.5
            cell.velocity = 500
            cell.velocityRange = 100
            cell.emissionRange = 2 * CGFloat(Double.pi)
            cell.contents = getRandomImage().cgImage
            cell.scale = 1
            cell.scaleRange = 0.5
            cell.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime()
            cells.append(cell)
        }

        emitter?.emitterCells = cells
        view.layer.addSublayer( emitter! )
    }

    func getRandomImage() -> UIImage {

        let upperBound = UInt32(particleImages.count)
        let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform( upperBound ))

        return particleImages[randomIndex]
    }


}
```

Comment: You are absolutely right, setting the CACurrentMediaTime() on the cells works, I have confirmed in my sample project. It is very odd behavior though and very poorly documented. Thank you for the solution I appreciate it!